# Rails: joining an array with em space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Is it possible to join an array with an [em space](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=8195&ent=emsp) in RoR?

**irb:**

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

a.join('    ')
#=> "a    b    c"

a.join('&#8195;')
#=> "a&#8195;b&#8195;c"

a.join('&#x2003;')
#=> "a&#x2003;b&#x2003;c"

a.join('&emsp;')
#=> "a&emsp;b&emsp;c"
```

But rendered by a browser, `a.join('&emsp;')` still spits out `a&emsp;b`.

Comment: What's the problem here? Is the result not what you were expecting? If so, what _is_ your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan No, this is not what I expected. I would like to see "a   b   c", with an em space in between, instead of several regular spaces.

Comment: In irb or plain Ruby you would simply write `a.join("\u2003")`. But since your question is related to Rails, you might want something else (e.g. a named HTML entity like `&emsp;`). That's why I was asking.

Comment: Once rendered by a browser will this not be correct?

Comment: @Kris, @Stefan Rendered by a browser my code `a.join('&emsp;')` still spits out `a&emsp;b`

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn Because you'll have to mark it as html safe. Otherwise html characters are escaped. `a.join('&emsp;').html_safe`

Comment: Thanks @JohanWentholt, since my method is in the model, that works perfect.

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn note that this will mark the whole string as being HTML safe, not just the separator. Don't do this if the strings in your array may contain special characters (let alone user provided data).

Answer (score 5):

> Rendered by a browser my code `a.join('&emsp;')` still spits out `a&emsp;b`

That's because Rails escapes special characters by default: `&` becomes `&amp;`, `<` becomes `&lt;` and so on. You have to explicitly mark a string containing HTML entities (or even tags) as being [`html_safe`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe):

```
'&emsp;'.html_safe
```

And since the built-in `join` would invalidate the HTML safe mark(s), Rails provides [`safe_join`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join):

```
<%= safe_join(['a', 'b', 'c'], '&emsp;'.html_safe) %>
```

Within a view, you can also use the [`raw`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) helper:

```
<%= safe_join(['a', 'b', 'c'], raw('&emsp;')) %>
```

Comment: Nice tip for using in the view, however I needed something that would work in a method, in which case what @JohanWentholt suggests does the job.

Comment: @JoannaGaudyn _"would work in a method"_ – you mean in the model? YMMV, but since the method outputs HTML, you might consider turning it into a view helper.

Comment: Yes, I meant either model or controller method. Thanks for the hint, might actually consider it.

Answer (score 1):

All is work as expected. But if you want to see white space instead of a code of HTML entities in your console, you must convert that into UTF-8 character. Try something like this:

```
CGI.unescapeHTML(%w[a b c].join('&#8195;')) #=> "a b c"
```